# How to mount Raw NAND images using Network Block Device (nbd) to access its files/folders?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

So, I've made a fresh image of my smartphone and now I want to play with it. I can mount SOME of its partitions using the linux `mount` comand giving the offset of the partition. For example, the state of the image is:

> $ gdisk -l imagem-thea-20180722.img
>   GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1
>
> Partition table scan:
>    MBR: protective
>    BSD: not present
>    APM: not present
>    GPT: present
>
> Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
>   Disk imagem-thea-20180722.img: 30777344 sectors, 14.7 GiB
>   Logical sector size: 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier (GUID): 98101B32-BBE2-4BF2-A06E-2BB33D000C20
>   Partition table holds up to 42 entries
>   First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 30777310
>   Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
>   Total free space is 70203 sectors (34.3 MiB)
>
> Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
>      1             256          131327   64.0 MiB    0700  modem
>      2          131328          132351   512.0 KiB   FFFF  sbl1
>      3          132352          132415   32.0 KiB    FFFF  DDR
>      4          132608          134631   1012.0 KiB  FFFF  aboot
>      5          135608          136007   200.0 KiB   FFFF  rpm
>      6          136608          137407   400.0 KiB   FFFF  tz
>      7          137608          137671   32.0 KiB    FFFF  sdi
>      8          137672          138695   512.0 KiB   FFFF  utags
>      9          138696          142791   2.0 MiB     FFFF  logs
>     10          142792          147455   2.3 MiB     0700  padA
>     11          147456          149479   1012.0 KiB  FFFF  abootBackup
>     12          150456          150855   200.0 KiB   FFFF  rpmBackup
>     13          151456          152255   400.0 KiB   FFFF  tzBackup
>     14          152456          152519   32.0 KiB    0700  sdiBackup
>     15          152520          153543   512.0 KiB   FFFF  utagsBackup
>     16          153600          154623   512.0 KiB   FFFF  frp
>     17          154624          155703   540.0 KiB   0700  padB
>     18          155704          158775   1.5 MiB     FFFF  modemst1
>     19          158776          161847   1.5 MiB     FFFF  modemst2
>     20          161848          162823   488.0 KiB   FFFF  hob
>     21          162824          162887   32.0 KiB    FFFF  dhob
>     22          163072          166143   1.5 MiB     FFFF  fsg
>     23          166144          166145   1024 bytes  FFFF  fsc
>     24          166146          166161   8.0 KiB     FFFF  ssd
>     25          166162          168209   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  sp
>     26          168210          168465   128.0 KiB   FFFF  cid
>     27          168466          174609   3.0 MiB     FFFF  pds
>     28          174610          182801   4.0 MiB     FFFF  logo
>     29          182802          190993   4.0 MiB     FFFF  clogo
>     30          191232          207615   8.0 MiB     0700  persist
>     31          207616          208639   512.0 KiB   FFFF  misc
>     32          208640          229039   10.0 MiB    FFFF  boot
>     33          229040          249599   10.0 MiB    FFFF  recovery
>     34          249600          251647   1024.0 KiB  0700  deviceinfo
>     35          251648          284415   16.0 MiB    0700  ftmlog
>     36          284416          300799   8.0 MiB     FFFF  kpan
>     37          300800          327679   13.1 MiB    0700  padC
>     38          327680          360447   16.0 MiB    FFFF  keystore
>     39          360448          425983   32.0 MiB    0700  oem
>     40          425984         4521983   2.0 GiB     0700  system
>     41         4521984         5033983   250.0 MiB   0700  cache
>     42         5033984        30711551   12.2 GiB    0700  userdata

```
$ file imagem-thea-20180722.img
imagem-thea-20180722.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

It was created by pulling it from the device with `adb`:

```
$ adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 ~/imagem-thea-20180722.img
```

So I can `mount` system and userdata partitions with:

```
$ sudo mount imagem-thea-20180722.img mount-dir/ -o offset=$((5033984*512))
```

passing the start of the sector, but this doesn't work for some parts like `boot`:

```
$ sudo mount imagem-thea-20180722.img mount-dir/ -o offset=$((208640*512))

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

in `dmesg` output pointing:

> [26910.003624] F2FS-fs (loop1): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0xe2632b02)
>   [26910.003625] F2FS-fs (loop1): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock

So, I read somewhere that NAND images can be manipulated using `nbd` but I didn't found an easy way to do so. Basically I have to setup a nbd-server to provide image file and with the nbd-client I mount it. But I don't know how to do so. Any help?

Comment: An image of raw NAND flash cannot be treated as a block device simply because it is not.   Linux uses [MTD](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/general.html) to make raw NAND accessible like a block device.  You need to determine what you actually have.

Comment: I've created the image by pulling it from the device with `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 ~/imagem-thea-20180722.img`. The output of `file` command is `imagem-thea-20180722.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)`

Comment: @sawdust, according to the link you provided, it is indeed a block device since it was obtained from an eMMC device, I also update my post to show how I obtained the image file

Comment: If you have an eMMC device, then your title is misleading.

Comment: sorry.. why? Doesn't eMMC uses NAND memory?